# Can't Copy Non-ASCII Characters

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, macos, iterm2, ascii

I can't copy Non-ASCII charaters from Neovim anymore when I select them with mouse or <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

For example, I have the Turkish word `Bankası` written in my editor. When I yank and paste it to somewhere else, what I see is `Bankasƒ±`.

In my `nvimrc` I only have:

```
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
end
set clipboard=unnamed
```

I have tried setting

1. `mouse=r`
2. `mouse=v`
3. `clipboard=unnamedplus`

but no luck and I can't seem to remember what's changed. Any idea how to fix this?

#### Additional info for comments:

> how do you copy exactly? What clipboard provider are you using? Have you tried a different one?

I have tried both `yy` and <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

Healthcheck does tell me, I use `pbcopy` and all is OK.

```
health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: pbcopy
```

No, I haven't tried anything else. I didn't know there was such an option other than `pbcopy`.

> Can you check the encoding settings of all apps? Is the character double-width in some way?

Other apps work fine. I can copy from VS Code to any other app just fine.

I don't know if it is double-width or not. It's a standard Turkish char that didn't cause any problems before.

Comment: You said it doesn't work _anymore_ so that could be a change in your config, so you might want to read [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841). It the problem doesn't come from your vimrc maybe you should try with another terminal emulator too.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It cannot be plug-in related because I have restarted from scratch and all I have is those 4 lines in my vimrc.

Comment: how do you copy exactly? What clipboard provider are you using? Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Can you check the encoding settings of all apps? Is the character double-width in some way?

Comment: Hi Christian Brabandt and D. Ben Knoble. I tried to add the info you have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Setting `LANG` to `tr_TR.UTF-8` did solve the issue.

```
export LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8
```

## Problem

Turns out `LANG` being empty was the root cause:

```
> locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I only checked through `AppleLocale`

```
> defaults read -g AppleLocale
en_TR
```

and assumed `en_TR` is a valid. However `locale -a` doesn't list such a thing. Don't know why `AppleLocale` is set as `en_TR` neither. ‍♂️